# access URL parameters without cookies

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

My application should work without cookies. How can I get the parameters of the URL from a java file if cookies are disabled.

`req.getParameter("abc")` gives `null` when I tried.

I've 3 spring GenericFilterBeans in this application and I can see the values inside filters. How can I make the parameters available to others controllers and other files..

Comment: can you post your code .   It should work

Comment: http://localhost:8080/context/login?code=049&val=yes

how can I acces the code and val from a java file. 

When I tried with 

 if (req.getParameter("code") != null) {
                code = req.getParameter("code");
            }
   
   It gives null

Comment: Where have you put this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence and accessibility of the request parameters is completely unrelated to the cookie support.

The cause of your problem lies somewhere else. Probably a programmatic redirect was involved which caused the parameters to lost. Or the request was modified/wrapped/replaced in an improper manner. Verify your filters.

Comment: +1 for Probably a programmatic redirect was involved which caused the parameters to lost. Verify your filters.

Comment: I've spring GenericFilterBean and I get the values in that filter... How can I pass it to the rest...

Comment: Does the URL in browser address bar automagically change to an URL without parameters? If so, then a redirect was involved. If not, then the problem lies deeper. Hard to tell without an SSCCE.

Comment: I can see the parameters in the URL. It's not changing. I can see the values in filters...

Comment: What do you mean with "I can see the values in filters"? This contradicts your problem.

Comment: I can see means I can access the values :)

Comment: after these 3 filters the login page loads and then I try to acces one java file from the login.jsp. And this java file is trying to get the parameters and there it is null. Still the values are there in the URL.

Comment: Apparently one of the filters has modified/wrapped the `request` object in an improper manner. Nail down the one and fix its code accordingly. Or if it's a 3rd party filter, report a bug to the filter's vendor/author.